# Date: Invalid Date Linux/Raspberry pi os

Tags: linux, date, raspbian

I know this is a fairly common question, but the answers I've seen before have not worked for me.

I'm simply trying to set the date. This was working a few months ago, and for some reason not anymore.

The command I'm using is :

> sudo date -s "2021_03_09 10:36:41"

I've tried many variations, such as

> sudo date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S -s "2021_03_09_10_36_41"

and I always get

> date: invalid date '2021_03_09 10:36:41'

I've also tried adding a time zone. Why would this happen all of a sudden?

Comment: I'm curious - what `locale` are/were you in?  Where is `2021_03_09` a valid date format?

Comment: I was almost certain that this was working earlier, but maybe i changed the dashes to underscores somewhere along the way. This raspberry pi is running a slightly different os to the one i wrote the script on. For all intensive purposes, its the latest stock version of rasberry pi os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dashes instead of the underscores.

```
sudo date -s '2021-03-09 10:36:41'
```

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb, this did it, Thanks

Comment: "Thanks" = upvote / accept :-)

Comment: It said I had to wait 8 minutes to give the accept. Done now